# after_update not triggering when using JS to call an update_all method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using JS sorting to call this method:

```
def sort
    params[:piece].each_with_index do |id, index|
      current_user.lineup.piece_lineups.update_all({position: index+1}, {piece_id: id})
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

and in my piece_lineup model I have:

```
after_update :update_associated_lineup
```

however it isn't getting triggered by that update_all call. am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update_all` method generates one SQL UPDATE query and that's all. It doesn't instantiate any ActiveRecord objects, so no validations or callbacks are triggered. To trigger callbacks you have to do something like that

```
piece_lineups = current_user.lineup.piece_lineups

params[:piece].each_with_index do |id, index|
  piece_lineups.
    select { |pl| pl.piece_id == id }.
    map { |pl| pl.update_attribute(:position, index + 1) }
end
```